# Python tkinter button command

Tags: python, tkinter, text, insert

I want to make an app that if you press a button it will print a letter in a textbox. I created the button:

```
Button(window, text="Button1", width=5,command = button1).grid(row = 3,column = 0)
```

And the textbox:

```
output = Text(window, width = 75, height=6, wrap=WORD, bg = "white")
output.grid(row = 13, column = 0)
```

Now I don't know what code to put in button command:

```
def button1():
    #idk what code to put
    #here, that will print
    #the letter 'A' in output
    #textbox
```

I'm new to tkinter so please help me with a piece of code that will print the letter "a" in output textbox. Thanks. No need of a huge explanation, jist a brief one to understand how it works.

Comment: Suggest you read one of the many tutorials about programming `tkinter` that are available.

Comment: @martineau Can you link one of them?

Comment: Take your pick: [Tkinter tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=python+tkinter+tutorial&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=)

Comment: I'll watch one.

Comment: There's also a bunch of existing questions here about using [`tkinter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+tkinter).

Comment: I know. I readed them but I couldn't find an anwser for my question

Comment: When you search for related questions here, besides using `[python]` and `[tkinter]` as tags, add additional terms like `text` and `insert` to the query. Also here's a somewhat dated [tkinter reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) I really like (and still use) because it's still mostly applicable.

Answer (score 1):

A minimalist example to get you started:

```
from tkinter import *  # for example purposes only!

def pressed():
    text.insert(END, 'Thank you!')

window = Tk()

Button(window, text="Press Me!", command=pressed).pack()

text = Text(window)
text.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Now follow available tutorials to build upon this.

Comment: I have built my app but I'm stuck at that. I want to print the text(in you example 'Thank You') in the textbox. Like I have watched tutorials but none of them showed me how to do this.

Comment: @ador007: When I run this code it adds `Thank you!` to the `Text` widget every time I click on the Button — so there must be something else wrong if that's not the case when you run it. If you want each one on a separate line, just add a newline to the end of the string. i.e. `text.insert(END, 'Thank you!\n')`